# Cannot get second image animation to work - whats going on?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to create a quick picture/movie viewer - for a birthday celebration.
First I want to show some pictures - then a movie - and then some pictures again. The first picture animation shows up fine, movie starts fine and catching AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification just fine to launch pictures again, - but second animation never starts - I cannot work this out ?? - DoShow1 is not working - please advice anybody out there ??

```
- (void)DoShow
    {
        NSArray *imageNames = @[@"1.jpg", @"2.jpg", @"3.png", @"4.png",
                                @"5.png", @"6.png",@"7.png", @"8.png",
                                @"9.png", @"10.png", @"11.png",@"12.png",
                                @"13.png"];

        NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (int i = 0; i < imageNames.count; i++) {
            [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageNames objectAtIndex:i]]];
        }

        _imageview.animationImages = images;
        _imageview.animationDuration = 10;
        _imageview.animationRepeatCount = 1;

        [_imageview startAnimating];

        [self performSelector:@selector(playmovie) withObject:nil afterDelay: 10];
    }



    - (void)DoShow1
        {

        NSArray *imageNames = @[@"14.jpg", @"16.jpg", @"18.jpg", @"19.jpg",
                                @"20.jpg", @"22.jpg",@"23.jpg", @"24.jpg"];

            NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            for (int i = 0; i < imageNames.count; i++) {
                [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageNames objectAtIndex:i]]];
            }

            _imageview2.animationImages = images;
            _imageview2.animationDuration = 2;
            _imageview2.animationRepeatCount = 100;

            [_imageview2 startAnimating];
    }

    - (void) playmovie
    {

        MyMusicPlayerManager *sharedManager = [MyMusicPlayerManager sharedManager];
        [sharedManager ChkPaused];

        NSBundle *Bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
        NSString *moviePath = [Bundle pathForResource:@"stine_ane" ofType:@"mp4"];
        NSLog(@"String is %@", moviePath);
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];

        AVPlayerItem *video = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:url];
        AVQueuePlayer *queue = [[AVQueuePlayer alloc] initWithItems:@[video]];
        video = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:url];

        [queue insertItem:video afterItem:nil];

        self.avmovieplayer =  [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];

        self.avmovieplayer.player = queue;

        [self presentViewController:self.avmovieplayer animated:YES completion:nil];

        self.avmovieplayer.player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(myMovieFinishedCallback:)
                                                     name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                                   object:[avmovieplayer.player currentItem]];

        [self.avmovieplayer setShowsPlaybackControls:YES];
        [self.avmovieplayer.player play];

    }


    - (void)myMovieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification *)notification {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];

        [self DoShow1];
    }



    - (IBAction)DoStart:(id)sender {
        [self DoShow];
    }
```

Comment: are you sure `DoShow1` is called ? is the imageView2 visible ?

Comment: imageView2 is visible and DoShow1 is being called - if I don't play the movie DoShow and DoShow1 works fine - its something with                   [self presentViewController:self.avmovieplayer animated:YES completion:nil]; - I think - and thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
    [self DoShow1];
```

this is probably calling in succession and animation doesnt start at the same time the view is being dismissed.

> try it in the completion handler which is called after the view is
>   dismissed

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [self DoShow1];
    }];
```

Comment: Thank you - thank you :) I will think about your help on sunday when I show the app to 40 guest to my daughters confirmation